# Le verbe totaliser

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, anglais, verbes

> They (the pdf files) total nearly 12,000 pages in length.

Peut-on rendre le verbe total par totaliser comme ci-dessous ?

> Ils (les fichiers pdf) totalisent près de 12 000 pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can translate as you said.

A more "familiar" possibility is  :

> Ils font environ 12000 pages

Answer (score 3):

It sounds right to me but I'd go for "compter", cause it sounds better.

**Ils comptent près de 12 000 pages**

Comment: Je ne suis pas entièrement d’accord. Avec "totaliser" il est clair que ce sont l’ensemble des pages, le total, qui fait 12000 pages, alors qu’avec "compter" il subsiste une ambiguité sur le fait’que chaque fichier fait 12000 pages.

Comment: Non, je suis pas d'accord avec cette remarque. Pour moi il n'y a pas d’ambiguïté car "ils" est au pluriel, donc cela signifie tous les fichiers pdf...Totaliser fait trop franglais à mon gout. De plus, on l'emploie peu en général. Par contre, une autre suggestion pourrait être "compte au total près de..."